# Appending to Seq in Scala does not compile

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In this code I'm trying to add values to a `Seq[Seq[String]]` structure, but the line shown below throws a compilation error, why is that?

```
var values2 = Seq[Seq[String]]()
values2 = values2 :+ Seq[String]()
for ( x <- 0 to 5) {
      values2(0) = values2(0) :+ (x + "")  // <-- value update is not a member of Seq[Seq[String]]
    }
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's happens because inner collection is immutable and you can't reassign it's value with `=`.

But you can use `update` method of it (similar to `copy` method on case-classes), so it'll be like this:

```
for ( x <- 0 to 5) {
  values2 = values2.updated(0, values2(0) :+ (x + ""))
}
```

Now you just coping `values2` collection with one element changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.collection.mutable

var values2 = mutable.Seq[mutable.Seq[String]]()
values2 = values2 :+ mutable.Seq[String]()
for (x <- 0 to 5) {
  values2(0) = values2(0) :+ (x + "")
}
```

You can solve this by explicitly using mutable.Seq instead of the default Seq, which is immutable.